# How to align to the "absolute right position" in a fixed header?

Tags: css

```css
.header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #ff509a;
   }
   
   .subTitle{
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 70px;
    float: right;
           margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
   }
   
   .content{
    width: 2000px;
    height: 3000px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <div class="subTitle">
    hello
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   
  </div>
```

Here is the code. The hello element should appear in the right when I scroll to the very right side. Please help!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. I can't tell from your code, or your snippet, or what you said about the issue. Please give more details.

Comment: ok, when I scroll to the end of right side, the hello element should appear. but I can't see it.

Comment: It's not showing up because you're not actually scrolling the `.header`, you're scrolling the `.content`. If you remove the `.content` from your example you'll see that the scrollbars disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add

```
position: fixed;
right:0;
```

to `.subTitle`

Job done!

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index:1;` to `.header`, and `position:absolute; z-index:2;left: 64%;/* or whatever spacing you want*/` to `.subTitle`. Don't forget to remove the `float` since it's no longer needed. [Here is a pretty good article on `z-index` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). So the CSS would look like this:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #ff509a;
  z-index: 1; 
}

.subTitle {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 70px;
  /* float: right; */
  /* margin-right: 20px; */
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  z-index: 2; /*z-index of 2 to overlay the .header element*/
  position: absolute; /*absolute positioning*/
  left: 64%; /*change this if needed*/
}
```